# App crashes due to module library dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, urbanairship.com, android-module

I have module in Android app. This module uses the Airship library. I have imported this module in my project and used it.

Scenario: If both my app and module gradle has the Airship library, everything works fine.

But, I think adding the same library at both places does't make sense, hence i removed it from the the app gradle (As the app does not have direct dependency on Airship lib). But app is crashing with the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions;
```

Comment: So if it works when its in both the app and the module but not when its only in the module-  doesn't that pretty much tell you what the solution should be?

Comment: I am a little confused here. If we are creating separate module to handle a specific functionality, why is it necessary for the app gradle to include dependencies that are only required by module gradle?

Comment: similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916991/transitive-dependencies-for-local-aar-library